# Storing data temporarily before inserting into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, caching, nosql, memcached

On my PHP site I send AJAX request every 10 seconds to the server and then I do something like this:

```
update users set points = points + 1 where id = 5
```

The problem is there are lots of MySQL updates and it's killing my server.

I want to store the points temporary somewhere and when 100 points accumulated for a user I will update the users table. So 1 insert instead of 100 inserts.

How should I store the data temporarily?

Requirements:
  - lots of update
  - storing at least 500MB data (I have enough memory if stored in memory)
  - (optional) the data should be there after a server restart if possible

Is memcached suitable for this? (lots of update)

Is there anything like memcached but with the option to write the data to the disk and restore it in case I restart the server?

Would APCu or MongoDB or a NoSQL database better for this?

Comment: Do you have an index on `users(id)`?

Comment: Yes, I have index. And it's an InnoDB table.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Redis](http://redis.io).  It might solve your problem easily.

It is a key value store like memcached.  I have found it to be a lot better for my needs.  It has [Atomic Increments](http://redis.io/commands/INCR) which can solve your exact problem.

And if I am right, It can save the data to disk too.

Comment: "A lot better" is pretty subjective.